How to implement forward: in RouterFunction to DispatcherHandler in WebFlux?
I have a WebFlux.fn setup that needs to "forward" some path to dispatcher (without doing a redirect). This is trying to emulate the WebMVC "forward:/" pattern.
In annnotated controllers I can do
// the forward: scheme doesn't seem to work in WebFlux
// so this is a forwarding contoller
@GetMapping("/somepath")
Mono<Void> forwardController(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    // same effect as forward:
    doSomething();
    // retarget the exchange
    exchange = exchange.mutate(... mutate request path ...)....build();
    return this.dispatcherHandler(exchange);
}

Now in RouterFunction handler I have:
someHandlerFunction(ServerRequest request) {
    // ????
    someExchange = magicMethodToConvert(request);

    // wrong return type Mono<Void> want Mono<ServerResponse>
    return this.dispatcherHandler(someExchange);
}

IOW: how to write a handler that "forwards" the request back up to DispatherHandler ?
